# How do I subscribe and stay in sync to the data from a Resolver Service

Tags: angular, typescript

What's the best way to implement this, I get an error when I do this:

> "Property 'resolve' in type 'DocumentaryResolverService' is not assignable >to the same property in base type 'Resolve'."

```
import { Documentary } from './../models/documentary.model';
import { DocumentaryService } from './documentary.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Resolve,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DocumentaryResolverService implements Resolve<Documentary> {
  constructor(private documentaryService: DocumentaryService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let slug = route.params['slug'];
    let documentary: Documentary;
    return this.documentaryService.get(slug).subscribe(result => {
        documentary = <Documentary> result;
        return documentary;
    });
  }
}
```

but if I do this I don't get an error but I want to wait until the  subscribe to observable is finish before returning documentary.

```
import { Documentary } from './../models/documentary.model';
import { DocumentaryService } from './documentary.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Resolve,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DocumentaryResolverService implements Resolve<Documentary> {
  constructor(private documentaryService: DocumentaryService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let slug = route.params['slug'];
    let documentary: Documentary;
    this.documentaryService.get(slug).subscribe(result => {
        documentary = <Documentary> result;
    });
    return documentary;
  }
}
```

I've tried to do this using async and await but it doesn't work

```
import { Documentary } from './../models/documentary.model';
import { DocumentaryService } from './documentary.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Resolve,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DocumentaryResolverService implements Resolve<Documentary> {
  constructor(private documentaryService: DocumentaryService) {}

  async resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    let slug = route.params['slug'];
    console.log(slug);
    console.log("resolver");
    let documentary: Documentary;
    await this.documentaryService.get(slug).subscribe(result => {
        return <Documentary> result;
    });
    return documentary;
  }
}
```

The resolver is called here:

```
import { DocumentaryService } from './../../../services/documentary.service';
import { Documentary } from './../../../models/documentary.model';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-documentary-detail',
  templateUrl: './admin-documentary-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-documentary-detail.component.css']
})
export class AdminDocumentaryDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  documentary: any;
  slug: string;
  documentarySubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private documentaryService: DocumentaryService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.documentary = data;
      console.log(this.route.data);
    })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.documentarySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your console.log should be console.log(data);

Answer (score 2):

Once you subscribe to the service and then return the data, it's no longer an Observable, you are returning an object of type Subscription. Your "resolve" function must result either Documentary, Observale<Documentary> or Promise<Documentary>.

Instead of subscribing, just return the Observable,

```
return this.documentaryService.get(slug);
```

Here's the Resolver API with example : 
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Answer (score 0):

To get the resolve data you need to add it into your AdminDocumentaryDetailComponent route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminDocumentaryDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
       documentary: DocumentaryResolverService
    }
  }
];
```